# vti_bin authentication for a site collection/sub-site

Tags: listdata.svc

I'm trying to retrieve data from a SharePoint 2010 list in SQL Server Integration Services using the OData connection but I am getting the error `HTTP status 400: Bad Request` in Visual Studio whilst there are no issues in Internet Explorer.

This [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22349/listdata-svc-returns-error-400-bad-request-in-visual-studio) suggests that anonymous authentication needs to be disabled for this to work.

I am not familiar with how SharePoint is configured with IIS, can anonymous authentication be disabled for this folder at the site collection/sub-site level or is this a global setting?

If this can be done at the site collection/sub-site level how is this done in IIS? Do site collections/sub-sites appear as individual sites in IIS?

I would have to request this change from our I.T. department and no doubt will be challenged on it so I want to be clear on the steps involved.